# What 3G standard is used in Egypt, and how much does it cost?

Tags: egypt, internet

I know they are UMTS country. Can I rent 3g modem for a week?

Comment: could you perhaps expand your text a bit - it's very brief and doesn't totally explain what you're after.  In theory you could spend from $0 to $1000000 depending on a plan, prepay, roaming, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 cell phone providers in Egypt:

- [Vodafone](http://www.vodafone.com.eg/vodafoneportalWeb/en/myWorld_mainPage)
- [Mobinil](http://www.mobinil.com)
- [Etisalat](http://etisalat.com.eg/etisalat/Etisalat_Portal_En/home/home.htm)

Each one of them provide wireless data connection. There are two types:

1- USB modem, which is the easiest way:

- [Vodafone USB modem](http://www.vodafone.com.eg/vodafoneportalWeb/en/P4000137531293542683098)
- [Mobinil USB modem](http://www.mobinil.com/Mobinilservices/InternetEverywhere.aspx)
- [Etisalat USB modem](http://etisalat.com.eg/etisalat/Etisalat_Portal_En/smartnet/internet_rateplans.htm)

Normally etisalat is the cheapest one.

The problem with this USB modem, is that you have to buy the USB modem (cheapest USB modem is 99LE (~17$).

You will have to buy some plan (e.x with etisalat, you pay 19LE to get 110MB with high speed internet, after 110MB ends, you will be degraded to 64Kbps, which is awfully slow). You can re-pay another 19LE and get another 110MB with high speed.

2- The other option is cell phone internet. You get cell phone data plan, and use tethering in you smart phone to give internet to your laptop. You can use the per/day plans, you buy credit with 3LE, which gives you about 15. You can go with this if your usage is REALLY light (twitter, facebook status, ...).

Comment: There is a way not to pay for the USB modem itself, when you buy an unlimited data plan for an ipad. they give you the modem anyway, I did it from Mobinil (150 E£) & Vodafone (170 E£) and in both cases they gave me the modem for free as they have to activate the sim card through the USB modem first before using it on an ipad.

Answer (score 1):

Egypt uses GSM phones, [on the 900 and 1800 Mhz bands](http://www.worldtimezone.com/gsm.html), and have freed up 2100 Mhz for 3G usage.

[Vodafone Egypt](http://shop.vodafone.com.eg/shop/rtl/chooseDevice.jsp?categoryId=cat80058&menuKey=mnit600006) has what they call 'USB Modems' which would be what you're after, and their [data plans page](http://shop.vodafone.com.eg/shop/plans/dataPlanConfiguration.jsp?menuKey=mnit1400021) would seem to indicate various prepay and postpaid options.   But you're probably better off just chatting to them when you get there to decide on your best option.

Comment: Can you help, what means:

Monthly Fees = 150 L.E. | Unlimited MB | Add ons: 30 L.E. gives you 1 GB

So its unlimited , but has additional megabytes

Comment: No I believe that means that for 30LE, you get 1Gb...wait...

Comment: Hmm, that's quite odd.  Perhaps it's like the UK where they call your initial plan 'unlimited' but you only get 500Mb, and pay more for extra.  I guess it's something to discuss when you get there. On some of their other pages they say it's unlimited browsing and 500Mb for downloads for another plan, so perhaps they have an app to track web stuff (TCP port 80), and anything else is charged extra for.

Comment: Also could you please expand the text in your question and be a bit more detailed - it'd really help future people looking for a similar thing.

Comment: Actually yes that kinda makes sense, if they install an app on your computer to use the modem, they could track what is unlimited (web browsing) but limit your downloads so that you're not downloading tons of movies, for example :)

Comment: This is true, Downloads will not affect your browsing but will affect your download speed, but not in the unlimited plan even browsing slows down a bit. Also the term "unlimited" to Egyptian phone companies means "limited". The unlimited plan is 9 Gb Mobinil & 7 Gb Vodafone, Mobinil's unlimited plan is for 150 L.E. up to 9 Gb of downlads then slows down or you pay 30 L.E. more for each additional Gb of downloads before your original 9 end. If they are already finished they charge you 0.25 L.E. for each extra Megabyte.